# Convergence in parameter implies convergence in distribution

Tags: probability, convergence, location-scale-family

I'm interested in the following question. It seems pretty elementary but I don't know where to actually find reference on it.

Suppose we have a scale (one parameter) distribution family $\{\mathcal{F}_{\sigma}, \sigma>0\}$. And further assume $\{X_i\}$ with $i\ge 1$ are random variables from this family, such that $X_i\sim \mathcal{F}_{\sigma_i}$ (with scale parameter $\sigma_i$).

If the paramter $\sigma_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\sigma$, do we have $X_n\xrightarrow[weak]{n\to\infty} X$ (convergence in distribution), where $X$ follows $\mathcal{F}_{\sigma}$.

Note that the commonly seen distribution family: $N(0,\sigma)$, $Laplace(location=0,\ scale=\sigma)$ or discrete distribution $Geom(p)$, etc. all have this satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct.  By convention, in probability "$\mathcal{F}$" is reserved to denote $\sigma$-fields rather than distribution functions. For this reason, I will replace $\mathcal{F}$ in your post with $F$ below.

Recall that by definition, $\{F_\tau: \tau > 0\}$ is a scale family if $F_\tau(x) = F_1(\tau^{-1}x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, where $F_1$ is a fixed distribution function.  Let $x_0$ be a continuity point of $F_\sigma$, i.e., $F_\sigma(y) \to F_\sigma(x_0)$ as $y \to x_0$. It then follows by $\sigma_n \to \sigma$ as $n \to \infty$ that $\sigma\sigma_n^{-1}x_0 \to x_0$, whence
\begin{align}
F_{\sigma_n}(x_0) = F_1(\sigma_n^{-1}x_0) = F_1(\sigma^{-1}\sigma\sigma_n^{-1}x_0) = 
F_\sigma(\sigma\sigma_n^{-1}x_0) \to F_\sigma(x_0),
\end{align}
which shows $F_{\sigma_n} \to_d F_\sigma$ as $n \to \infty$.  This completes the proof.

Comment: That looks nice. Thanks for the proof. I’m wondering if the family $\mathcal{F}$ is an arbitrary family, we generally don’t have any conclusion like this, right?

Comment: @YuyuanWang As you may observe from the proof above, any family that allows absorbing the parameter into the argument of the target distribution function should  have the same result.  An "arbitrary family" of course does not have a similar conclusion (for example, consider a family of a fixed normal distribution and many exponential distributions, say).